# Clarification on DDD - How to prevent loop holes when adding new requirements?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm new to `DDD` and I'm learning and practicing it with `C#`. However, I got stuck with a scenario that hints me a possible loophole in my domain.

Requirements:

1. `Customer Loyalty Point` needs to be added when the customer places an `Order`.
2. `Customer Loyalty Point` can be `redeemed` when the customer has a minimum of 250 loyalty points.
3. `Customer Loyalty Point` needs to be `adjusted` with difference when the `Customer updates the existing Order`

I have a simple `CustomerEntity` with a `LoyaltyPoint` value object.

```cs
public class CustomerEntity 
{
    public LoyaltyPoint LoyaltyPoint { get; private set; }

    public void AddLoyaltyPoint(LoyaltyPoint loyaltyPoint)
    {
        LoyaltyPoint += loyaltyPoint;
    }

    public void RedeemLoyaltyPoint(LoyaltyPoint loyaltyPoint)
    {
        if (loyaltyPoint != 0 && (LoyaltyPoint < 250 || loyaltyPoint > LoyaltyPoint))
            throw new Exception();

        LoyaltyPoint -= loyaltyPoint;
    }
}
```

When `Customer` places an `Order`, the `Order Aggregate` will calculate loyalty points based on order amount and call `AddLoyaltyPoint` on the `Customer`.

```cs
public class OrderEntity
{

    public CustomerEntity Customer { get; private set; }

   public void AdjustCustomerLoyaltyPoint()
    {
        if (previousLoyaltyPoint == loyaltyPoint) return;
        
        if (previousLoyaltyPoint > loyaltyPoint)
        {
            Customer.RedeemLoyaltyPoint(previousLoyaltyPoint - loyaltyPoint);
        }
        else
        {
            Customer.AddLoyaltyPoint(loyaltyPoint - previousLoyaltyPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Customer` can redeem loyalty points when they have a minimum loyalty point value of 250.

The above logic works well so far for first 2 requirements.

But for the third, The `Customer` can place an `Order` and can update the same `Order`. So the `Customer` tries to remove one of the items in the `Order`. Now the `Order Aggregate`  will calculate the difference in loyalty points and needs to subtract the difference. I decided to reuse the `RedeemLoyaltyPoint` to do the subtraction but the `if` check fails and throws an `exception`. This happens for the new customer.

For example, the `Customer` has 0 loyalty point and places an `Order` and gains 5 loyalty points. Now the `Customer` updates the same `Order` and the loyalty point becomes 4 for the same order. So the difference value of 1 (5-4) needs to be adjusted so that the customer will have finally 4 loyalty points.

Now since the `RedeemLoyaltyPoint` will throw exception, I decided to introduce `ReduceLoyaltyPoint` as shown below,

```cs
public void ReduceLoyaltyPoint(LoyaltyPoint loyaltyPoint)
{
    LoyaltyPoint -= loyaltyPoint;
}
```

But does this bring a loophole in the domain? What is the guarantee that no developer in the future will call `ReduceLoyaltyPoint` by mistake to redeem loyalty points? This will bring a loophole to subtract without checking minimum loyalty point conditions `(LoyaltyPoint < 250 || loyaltyPoint > LoyaltyPoint)`.

Please can you assist on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

When tracking values (quantities/amounts) an `Account` of sorts may come in handy.

Any entity may have an `n` number of accounts.  In your case, a customer would have a `Loyalty` *quantity* account.  The transactions are then performed against the account.

In your example, an order may be placed and you add a transaction for adding, say, 5 points.  The customer then changes the order and you add another transaction for -1 points with the relevant description.  The account balance is what may be redeemed.

Using this approach you could award a customer `x` number of points every so often for reasons other than placing an order, such as for every year of loyalty.

How all the moving bits fit together is another discussion but you could make use of domain services, which you do when functionality does not naturally fit on a specific aggregate root. You could also message and a mediator and the like but that is something that would need to fit into your current architecture/design.